# Linking up Angular & Node.js: TypeError: error.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular

I am studying a course to link up node.js and Angular. I am following the tutorial, but I get an error and I don't know what to do with it. Can anyone help?

**This is the error I get**

> TypeError: error.json is not a function
>       at CatchSubscriber.eval [as selector] (message.service.ts?5cfd:25)
>       at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js?0867:104)
>       at MapSubscriber._next (map.js?c4af:82)
>       at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js?215e:90)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.js?7a71:1591)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?fad3:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js?223c:4744)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js?fad3:420)
>       at Zone.runTask (zone.js?fad3:188)
>       at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js?fad3:495)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js?fad3:1536)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js?fad3:1562)

**And these are the files.**

**Message input component** Here I enter the content of the new message:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {MessageService} from "./message.service";
import {Message} from "./message.model";
import {NgForm} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-message-input',
    templateUrl: './message-input.component.html'
})

export class MessageInputComponent {

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService){
    }

    onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
        const message = new Message(form.value.content, 'Tijl')
        this.messageService.addMessage(message)
            .subscribe(
                data => console.log(data),
                error => console.error(error)
            );
        form.resetForm()

    }
}
```

**Message service** : Here I connect to the Node.js back-end

```
import {Message} from "./message.model";
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/rx';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";


@Injectable()
export class MessageService {
    private messages: Message[] = [];

    constructor(private http: Http){}

    addMessage(message: Message) {
        this.messages.push(message)
        // turn your message into json format
        const body = JSON.stringify(message);
        // pass this body to the post request
        // we subscribe in the component itself, so not in this service. We need the data
        // in the component so that's where we'll subscribe to it
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/message', body)
            // json method allows to extract the data (not headers and such)
        // and convert it to Javascript object
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
    }
}
```

**The back-end route file it connects to:**

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var Message = require('../models/message');

```
router.post('/', function (req,res,next){
    var message = new Message({
        content: req.body.content
    });
    message.save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'An error occurred',
                error: err
            });
        }
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Saved message',
            // this object is what we'll receive in the front-end
            // and what we'll convert using the response.json() method
            obj: result
        })
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `Observable.throw(error.json())` did you mean `Observable.throw(error.json)`

Comment: @SergeK. No, OP is right. `.json()` is usually how you extract the payload from a response.

Comment: Well, I followed the tutorial. Let me try it without the '()'

Comment: if `error` is already in JSON format, just use it as is. `.catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error))`

Comment: When I do that I get the following error:

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Response.Body.json (http.js?7a71:1091)

Comment: in the message input component file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys,

I found what went wrong. The code was fine, I just forgot to restart the server after making changes.